# How to get last successful build from jenkins job using hudson classes and groovy

Tags: jenkins, groovy, hudson

I am trying to get the last successful build from a job in jenkins so that when another condition is meet details from that build will then be passed to another job.  I am trying to use Hudson's Run class since it has methods to get the last successful build, but I can't get it to compile. Since all my builds have failed, for now I am using getPreviousFailedBuild() instead, but it will be swapped for successful build later. Currently I have this:

```
import hudson.model.Run.*

def lastFailedBuild = getPreviousFailedBuild()
```

currently I get this error message when I try and run my script

`Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: hudson7682146427918660061.getPreviousFailedBuild() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
at hudson7682146427918660061.run(hudson7682146427918660061.groovy:5)`

I was getting errors with the import statement till I added the `.*` at the end, and I also tried calling the method like this:
`Run.getPreviousFailedBuild()` However that would result in a no such property Run exception instead.

What do I need to have in order to access my previous builds Hudson classes so I can send on the info I need to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `execute system groovy script`

```
def lastSuccess = build.getProject().getLastSuccessfulBuild()
```

Comment: This worked for me except I needed getLastSuccessfullBuild() instead, but Thank you for the help, couldn't have done it without you

Answer (score 2):

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins

def test_job = Jenkins.instance.getItemByFullName("My-Test-Dev")

last_sucessful_build_number=test_job.getLastSuccessfulBuild().getNumber()   

println last_sucessful_build_number
```

Comment: Maybe it's better if you format the proposed code and add any explanation